# Text Not Ellipsis at certain point using jQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I currently have a 'widget' div which has a static height, within it is an image which also has a static height. The only thing that can have a dynamic height is the title which can change from 1-3 lines long.

What's happening is that I'm trying to make the description within the div (which can be quite long) ellipsis before the containing div ends, taking into account the title which can vary in height.

I'm using a jQuery plugin called dotdotdot which docs can be found here http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/

The plugin is working but I think my JS might be off a bit. Would love some help as I just can't get my brain around it.

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/v92vace8/)

You can see it clearly on the fiddle but JS below.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

      $(".caption").each(function () {

          var authorheight = $('.meta').height();
          var h2height = $('h4').height();

          $(".desc").height(250 - h2height - authorheight);

          $(".desc").dotdotdot({
              after: "a.readmore"
          });
      });

  });
```

Any help would be brilliant!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were doing everything right except for calculating the Height.

```
 var authorheight = $('.meta').innerHeight();
 var h2height = $('h4').innerHeight();
```

the above help you get the height along with the padding and everything.

Then next id you left padding which you have applied to `.caption` so your 
height for `.desc` becomes as below

```
$(".desc").height(250 - h2height - authorheight -40);
```

[UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v92vace8/3/)

Comment: Hmm, this is not working on all my divs.  All finishing at different heights. E.g. The title with 2 lines is ellipsis a line after the title with 1 line.

Comment: @Jonathan in that too you didnt do what ever i said you were using your older code.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v92vace8/7/ If the title is 1 line, it seems to finish 1 line too early? This Fiddle illustrates the issue.

Comment: As you can see the large gap underneath the first div block, this only occurs when the title is 1 line.

Comment: @Jonathan the problem was not with the answer its with the way how the selectors are used see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v92vace8/9/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76056/discussion-between-kawinesh-sk-and-jonathan).

Comment: Started chat with you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: My console.log is coming back 'null' for h2height. But the example you've linked on JSfiddle works fine?